# How can I format edittext address with comma?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher, addtextchangedlistener

For example: string address = "400 pine st seattle wa" 
I want the output will be: "400 pine st, seattle, wa" aftertext changed?
I want a method that will work with all us address with street, city and state. Thank you

Comment: That depends how the regular input is. Is it always: Number-Street-Place?

Comment: But I dont think its possible. Because some streets include two words and so on. How to decide what is street and what is country?

Comment: I think so too, some street has more than 2 words, so it is really hard to decide

Comment: You could try to look for keywords like St, Ln, Dr, etc and insert the commas accordingly. Not straightforward but definitely doable to cover 80-90% of cases. To ensure errors don't get through, maybe you can present your modified address and ask user if it is ok to use that one. I have seen this done on many websites where they format accordingly their criteria and then ask for user confirmation about correctness of the result.